# Akka- redirect log file between child actors

Tags: scala, log4j, akka, akka-actor

I'm currently using log4j property `RollingFileAppender` to redirect the logs to a file, and the log file name is defined by a process argument:

log4j.properties:

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=-${filename}
```

Calling the process with args: `-Dfilename=childActor1`

The actor is defined as: `class MyActor extends Actor with ActorLogging`

This works fine for remote actors, but now I want to create local child actors and redirect the log file to a file with the name of the actor. 
I've read I can use `RoutingAppender` to switch logs between threads, but I'm not sure how is that integrated with Akka.

I feel like there should be some kind of simple solution to do that but I can't find it, and the Akka documentation for logging is really poor.